# JavaScript SumSub integration for KYC verification trouble - Error 401 when passing the generated token

Tags: javascript

I want to integrate the SumSub KYC verification into my JavaScript application.

I used the same code as in the example in the docs, here: https://developers.sumsub.com/web-sdk/#frontend-integration-general

I generated the token with the permission on the console in SumSub.

I than integrate this token in my code. My code looks like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>WebSDK CDN Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>test</p>
    <script src="https://static.sumsub.com/idensic/static/sns-websdk-builder.js"></script>
    <div id="sumsub-websdk-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
// import snsWebSdk from '@sumsub/websdk';

/**
  * @param accessToken - access token that you generated on the backend
with levelName: kyc-sl-group
  */
function launchWebSdk(accessToken) {
     let snsWebSdkInstance = snsWebSdk.init(
             accessToken,
             // token update callback, must return Promise
             () => this.getNewAccessToken()
         )
         .withConf({
             lang: 'en', 
         })
         .on('onError', (error) => {
           console.log('onError', payload)
         })
         .onMessage((type, payload) => {
           console.log('onMessage', type, payload)
         })
         .build();

     // you are ready to go:
     // just launch the WebSDK by providing the container element for it
     snsWebSdkInstance.launch('#sumsub-websdk-container')
}

function getNewAccessToken () {
    return Promise.resolve()
}
    launchWebSdk('prd:01Xwjxxxxxxxxxi98d')
</script>
```

So the token structure is like: 'prd:01Xwjxxxxxxxxxi98d'

This is the token which was generated in the SumSub developer portal and I allways get error 401, unauthorized. But I am not really sure if I need some other token from this token or what.. There is really not a good documentation for SumSub web sdk integration.

Thanks to everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation says
**Make sure that an accessToken was provided to the SDK initialization function (it has a format like _act-b8ebfb63-5f24-4b89-9c08-5bbabeec986e**

Also, you must get this token by implementing their API to get access token,
you can also check this:
https://developers.sumsub.com/api-reference/#app-tokens

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).